# The type 'x' in 'x.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'x'

Tags: c#

What is causing this build error?

The type '*AriaLibrary.AriaBL.Book*' in

> 'I:\Programing\MyProgram\Library\AriaNetDelijanCorporation\AriaLibrary\AriaBL\AriaBL.cs'

*conflicts with the imported type*

> 'AriaLibrary.AriaBL.Book' in
>
> 'i:\Programing\MyProgram\Library\AriaNetDelijanCorporation\AriaLibrary\bin\Debug\AriaLibrary.exe'.
>
> Using the type defined in
>   'I:\Programing\MyProgram\Library\AriaNetDelijanCorporation\AriaLibrary\AriaBL\AriaBL.cs'.
>
> I:\Programing\MyProgram\Library\AriaNetDelijanCorporation\AriaLibrary\UI\Document\Book\frm_AddNewBookISO.cs   24  16  AriaLibrary

Comment: Well... have you tried reading it?

Comment: Good point - but it is a genuine question. Should we not be more of a community and edit the question to be slightly more relevant? There is a good answer posted.

Comment: This "not a real question" saved me a great amount of time. I wish I could vote to reopen it

Comment: I don't see any reasons why this is a "not real question". In my case it was building fine, but the underlined class names and messy output was annoying. The reason was I had a self-reference. Vote up for OP and first answer.

Comment: I also wish I could vote to reopen this "not a real question". Thanks user818566 for asking such a good not-question.

Comment: This happened to me in an ancient webforms project in Visual Studio 2015 such that code in App_Code was being compiled twice which made it ambiguous.

Answer (score 53):

You have added a reference to the output of the project.

In other words, when trying to compile your project, AriaLibrary, to produce AriaLibrary.exe, the compiler imports the assembly AriaLibrary.exe. On disk, this file exists from a previous build.

As such, the compiler finds two of that class, one that it tries to compile now, and one from that previous build, and thus you get the warning.

Since there is no valid reason for having the output a project being imported as a reference to itself, you can safely remove that reference.

Check the references list of the AriaLibrary project and remove the reference with the same name, AriaLibrary.

Comment: Thank you. Simple and stupid mistake but not evident to guess at the first glance.

Comment: I found a reference that has the exactly same name with my own project. After getting rid of that, I could successfully build my app. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

This happens when a Type namespace in your code has the same signature as a namespace in an imported DLL.

So in your case it seems you have a namespace `AriaLibrary.AriaBL.Book` in your code which also exists in a referenced assembly