# The type X in Y conflicts with the imported type X in Z

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, .net-assembly

I have the following warning on a interface :

> The type 'DevExpress.Data.Browsing.Design.IColumnImageProvider' in
>   c:\Users[MyUser]\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\ReportFiles\CustomReportFieldListIcons.cs
>   conflicts with the imported type
>   'DevExpress.Data.Browsing.Design.IColumnImageProvider' in 'C:\Program
>   Files(x86)\DevExpress\DXperience13.1\Bin\Framework\DevExpress.XtraTreeList.v13.1.dll'
>   Using the type defined in 'c:\Users[MyUser]\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\PRojects\XtraReportTest\XtraReportTest\ReportFiles\CustomReportFieldListIcons.cs'

Why? I have checked the references and can´t see that there is anything wrong there?

Comment: Duplicate [conflicts with the imported type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073806/conflicts-with-the-imported-type)

Comment: Why don't you contact DevExpress support directly?

Comment: Because this smells like a regular .NET problem. I have another solution where this works fine but I can´t see the difference between the projects.

Comment: Had this issue when I reverted to a target framework of 4.0 from 4.5.2.  Had classes in my App_Code folder where they called methods in each other.  When I created a standard folder called "AppCode" and moved my files into it, I no longer had the issue.  If I re-created the "App_Code" folder and moved my classes back into that, I had the issue again.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073806/warning-the-type-x-in-y-cs-conflicts-with-the-imported-type-x-in-z-dll/37846370#37846370

Comment: This happened to me in an ancient webforms project in Visual Studio 2015 such that code in App_Code was being compiled twice which made it ambiguous.

Comment: Adding a self-reference will do it too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790240/the-type-x-in-x-cs-conflicts-with-the-imported-type-x

Answer (score 20, accepted):

- **Remove** the project's **Bin** and **Obj** folders;
- **Clean** and **Rebuild** the project.

Comment: Thanks but that do not help. The same problem returns when building.

Comment: This one solved the issue for me. My case: 1 big solution, multiples projects, 1 web site migrated from DevExpress 11.x to 13.x; all types were duplicated on both 11.x and 13.x DLLs. After cleaning up Bin and Obj folders (just for the website project); the problem disappears.

Comment: Surprisingly this answer actually did the job

Comment: In addition to this I also had to clear the nuget cache with `nuget.exe locals -clear all`