# CS0436: Warning as Error: Why I am getting this error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

> CS0436: Warning as Error: The type 'Time_Tracker.App_Code.DataManager' in 'c:\Users\EPS\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5f0630b6\64f04a01\App_Code.zvy6z-ld.0.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'Time_Tracker.App_Code.DataManager' in 'c:\Users\EPS\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5f0630b6\64f04a01\assembly\dl3\091dfa48\431f4eb0_5db7d201\Time Tracker.DLL'. Using the type defined in 'c:\Users\EPS\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\5f0630b6\64f04a01\App_Code.zvy6z-ld.0.cs'.

[image]

Comment: move it out of App_Code and if there remains a copy in that folder that is not part of the Solution, delete it.

Comment: I think this question was already answered. Duplicate with:
[The type X in Y conflicts with the imported type X in Z](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18825452/the-type-x-in-y-conflicts-with-the-imported-type-x-in-z)

Comment: @Nova this is probably a duplicate, but not of that. This is a thing with App_Code folder which causes things to compile twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

****The namespace NamespaceName1 in NamespaceName2 conflicts with the type TypeName1 in NamespaceName3****

This error occurs when the imported type and the imported namespace have the same fully qualified name. When that name is referenced, the compiler is unable to distinguish between the two.