# What horrible thing happens if I ignore CS0436 "type X conflicts with the imported type X" when the same file is included into two projects?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a setup similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8073806/57428) - the same .cs file is included into more than one project (technically it resides in on project and a shortcut is added to the other so there's one copy of the file at all times) and then one of those projects is referenced from another one and I get `type X conflicts with the imported type X` warning. I know that I can fix this by [crafting a class library referenced from both projects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8073883/57428), but it's extra work that I'd rather avoid right now.

Is it safe to ignore the warning in this scenario? What bad things can happen?

Answer (score 1):

The two types will not be interchangeable. You can *have* both declared separately, but they will be completely separate types. Type resolution can be really awkward - especially if an `extern` alias isn't possible. If they never leave the calling scope, that might be fine. However, in the general case it **isn't a good idea** and should be avoided. Type mismatch at runtime would be very likely, as could be type resolution failures at compile-time.

Another option *in the future* might be [*assembly neutral* types](http://davidfowl.com/assembly-neutral-interfaces-implementation/); this doesn't apply unless the compiler framework handles it - and it might be limited to the asp.net mvc stack for all I know, but *in theory*:

```
[AssemblyNeutral, AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class
    | AttributeTargets.Interface | AttributeTargets.Struct,
    AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
internal sealed class AssemblyNeutralAttribute : Attribute { }
```

then whack `[AssemblyNeutral]` on your type.

Answer (score 0):

Found this:

> You have added a reference to the output of the project.
>
> In other words, when trying to compile your project, AriaLibrary, to
>   produce AriaLibrary.exe, the compiler imports the assembly
>   AriaLibrary.exe. On disk, this file exists from a previous build.
>
> As such, the compiler finds two of that class, one that it tries to
>   compile now, and one from that previous build, and thus you get the
>   warning.
>
> Since there is no valid reason for having the output a project being
>   imported as a reference to itself, you can safely remove that
>   reference.

here:[The type 'x' in 'x.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'x'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790240/the-type-x-in-x-cs-conflicts-with-the-imported-type-x)

But in answer to your actual question, I'm (guessing) you could have issues from collisions/etc and form run time errors due to this?